# How do I cover up this partially exposed brick?

Tags: walls, brick, plaster

Looks like someone tried to parge this brick and then put a layer of skim coat over it? I tried to take off everything that was already crumbling off and what's left is pretty stuck on there. Any ideas?

I'm pretty new to all of this so the more detail (such as products and methods to use) the better.

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would not even mess with that. Trying to apply some substance to the brick will be a very tricky operation.

The best option is probably to build a drywall box closely around it. Doing that guarantees that everything will be flat and easy.

Two notes:

(1) Make sure the boundary areas at the top and bottom are absolutely sealed off, not even a pencil should slip through. Otherwise such spaces can be used by rodents and other vermin to travel around inside the walls of the house.

(2) If any cords or wire would be run at any point in the future through there, install thinwall EMT as necessary and attach it to the brick so it cannot move.

Answer (score 1):

Replaster over it? Frame some studs along that wall and close off with drywall?

Comment: how would one replaster over it? There looks to be crumbling mortar all over it from a previous parge attempt.

Comment: Well I guess you scrape, wire brush and chisel off all the loose stuff. It seemed like you implied that was already nearly completed when you said "what's left is pretty stuck on there". It would seem to me that if the remaining material is a plaster compound and is solid and really "stuck on there" that you should be able to plaster right over that.